# Function that only returns false returns nothing

Tags: php

```
function return_true () {
    return true;
}

function return_false () {
    return false;
}

echo return_true(); //outputs 1
echo return_false(); //outputs nothing
```

why can't I echo out return_false and get 0 ? Apologies if this has been asked before but I didn't find anything that answers this question. Note: I am not saying this is something that needs to be done, I was just messing around with bools in PHP and found this odd.

Comment: Becouse there is nothing to show. Becouse false = null or 0 in somecases.

Comment: Because you made the mistake of assuming that PHP had simple consistent rules: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.casting.  (More generally, http://www.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php.)

Comment: you can not output false.
try var_dump(), or echo (int) return_false();

Comment: The function returns false correctly as it should; but `echo` will not display any value for a false... use var_dump() if you want to see details of the returned value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `var_dump()` instead of `echo` and you will get your desired result.

`echo` will output a string and a boolean false echoed as a string will always be nothing / empty

Answer (score 0):

if you want to check with your return type you can check with php function var_dump()

```
echo var_dump(return_true()); //outputs 1
echo var_dump(return_false()); //outputs nothing
```

it will print

**OUTPUT**

```
bool(true) 
bool(false)
```